# Using .AsString or .Text?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I have just seen a bit of code (D5) where they used...

```
aStr:=tblAcct.FieldByName('Name').Text;
```

It seems to work fine but I have always used...

```
aStr:=tblAcct.FieldByName('Name').AsString;
```

I have used both when loading a TMemo and again there seems no difference.

```
aMemo.Lines.Text:=tblAcct.FieldByName('History').Text;
aMemo.Lines.Text:=tblAcct.FieldByName('History').AsString;
```

Is there a reason why I should use one over the other?
If so, which one?

Actually for TMemo, I usually use...

```
aMemo.Lines.Assign(tblAcct.FieldByName('History'))
```

which seems to work fine too.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`Text`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TField.Text) property is meant to be used to obtain the textual representation of a field being edited in a DataAware control, in contrast with the [`DisplayText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TField.DisplayText) property that gives you a string to represent the value to the user (it may contain punctuation or other *decoration* to the plain value).

> Contains the string to display in a data-aware control when the field is in edit mode

A typical example is a TFloatField with the `Currency` property set to `True`. The `DisplayText` gives you a string with the number containing commas (if needed), the decimal separator and a currency symbol. The `Text` property gives you a string without commas or currency symbol.

```
begin
  MyFloatField.Currency := True;
  MyFloatField.AsFloat := 1234.56;
  A := MyFloatField.Text; //'1234.56'
  B := MyFloatField.DisplayText; //'$1,234.56', depends on your locale
end;
```

Both above properties can be customized writing a [`OnGetText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TField.OnGetText) event handler where you can write custom logic to *convert* the value to a string representation. The `DisplayText` parameter indicates if the wanted string is meant to represent the value for edit or not.

On the other hand, the `AsString` property uses a more plain conversion between the base data type and string. Each TField descendant implements the virtual GetAsString method using functions from the RTL to perform that representation. Following the TFloatField example, this class calls [`FloatToStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.FloatToStr) for that purpose.

All this said, the **answer to your question is**: `AsString` returns the same string as the `Text` property if there's no OnGetText event handler, but it may be different if there's a event handler or a non-standard TField descendant.

I can't tell what is more appropriate for you, because it depends on what's the intended use for the returned value, but if you're using it to display the values to the user in the UI (as your code example), I advise you to use the DisplayText property.

Comment: @jachguate Thanks for a very detailed answer. OK, now I know that there is a significant difference it may explain why I have been having a problem with a Locate call giving me seemingly incorrect results. Not why I asked the question, but your detail has me going back to the Locate issue and rethinking that approach. It's an ill wind...

Answer (score 2):

`AsString` contains field's value as string.

`Text` contains the string to display in a data-aware control when the field is in edit mode.

So in your case I think you should use AsString.

Comment: Thanks @Riho, that simplifies another issue I was having, also unrelated to this question, but your comment has cleared things up too.