# What is the value returned by AsString when FieldByName('fieldname') has null value?

Tags: delphi

What value does `val`, which is of string type, get when the column named `fieldName` is `null` for the selected row? Here `myQry` is a database query.

```
val := myQry.FieldByName('fieldName').AsString
```

Here column `fieldName` does exist in the table, but for the selected row/record, the value is `null`. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15768809/3375713). It was informative, but didn't have the information I needed I am afraid. I also looked at [this](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TField_AsString.html) but that didn't help much either.

Comment: just debug it and look at the value in val after this line of code and then you know

Comment: note that you'll get an EDatabaseError exception with message _'<dataset>: Field '<fieldname>' not found'_ in case which `myQry` doesn't have a field named _'fieldName'_. Otherwise, you'll get an empty string `''`

Comment: @GuidoG I would if I could. I don't have *anything* where I can run delphi codes. All I am doing is converting an old project done in delphi into C#.

Comment: So you get to decide what behaviour you want.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually I can't. Because the original project isn't mine, so I don't always know the behaviour *they* wanted.

Comment: You are going to need to be able to debug the program and read the Delphi library code to do this in my view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can test this yourself simply by calling

```
MyDataSet.FieldByName('MyField').Clear
```

That sets MyField to `Null` and, after that, calling `AsString` on it returns an empty (zero-length) string.

The `GetAsString` method of TField descendants typically contain code like this:

```
function TIntegerField.GetAsString: string;
var
  L: Longint;
begin
  if GetValue(L) then Str(L, Result) else Result := '';
end;
```

Here, `GetValue` succeeds if it is possible to retrieve a value from the current record buffer.  If it fails, the field is taken to contain `Null`.

Comment: This answer is even better and more explanatory. I did not want to show the code of the AsString, but you did that.

Comment: @ZENsan:  Thanks.  I too hesitate to quote too much of EMBA's proprietary source, but a minimal extract like this typically constitutes "fair use" under copyright legislation, I think.

Answer (score 6):

Typically, depending on the actual type of field, the empty string is returned. But this does depend on the implementation of the `TField` descendant, and you have given no indication of what that is.

In order to distinguish between null and an empty string, use the [`IsNull`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TField.IsNull) property of the field.

Comment: And what is returned when column is non-text type?

Comment: Depends on the implementation of the field descendant. Presumably you know what this field really is? If it can be null then surely you will want an IsNull check?

Comment: AFAIK, All (out of the box) TField.AsString descendants return empty string on null value. but yes, one might implement the method otherwise theoretically.

Answer (score 4):

AsString returns the String value for the field if it has value or the empty string if it does not have the value.
AsString does not use DisplayText or other things.
It is absolutely safe to call AsString on NULL value fields.